# Find tangent points on a curve from a user-given point outside the curve

Tags: matlab, geometry, curve-fitting, polynomials

I am trying to find the tangent lines from a given point outside a closed curve (not on the curve). The curve is defined as 2D x and y coordinates of points，shaped like an irregular ellipse for example.

If given a point by the user: (x0,y0) = (-30,80), how can I know the tangent points (obviously closest point among discrete points from the smooth curve) on curve (i.e. tangent lines from (x0,y0) to curve)?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any code that shows your attempts?

Comment: Yeah, I tried one idea: 1) for each point on curve, get previous 30 and next 30 points in order to fit a polynomial curve segment f(x), using p = polyfit(ragx, ragy, 10). Then using polyder(p) to get the slope of the polynomial curve f'(x) and then solve an equation: where the slope of the tangent line is f'(xi):  y0 - f(xi) = f'(xi) * (x0 - xi), to obtain the tangent point on curve xi. Do this for all points (maybe every second one) and limit them into ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to use numerical differentiation to find the tangent line at every point, and decide whether it passes "close enough" to the given point. However, one has to think hard about "close enough" to avoid getting either no matches or too many.

Here is another approach: consider the unit vectors pointing from the given point (x0,y0) to the points on the curve. Find the largest gap between them (the command convhull helps here). The vectors on both sides of the gap determine tangent lines.

In general this will find only two tangent lines, not all of them. But if the curve is convex, there are only two tangent lines anyway.

Here is an example of the tricky situations where the given point is within the convex hull of the curve.

[image: tricky]

The code that produced the above picture:

```
t = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
x = 10*cos(t) + sin(7*t);
y = 6*sin(t) + cos(13*t);                 % x,y  describe the curve; 

x0 = 4; y0 = 5;                           % given point 

xn = (x-x0)./sqrt((x-x0).^2+(y-y0).^2);   % unit vectors 
yn = (y-y0)./sqrt((x-x0).^2+(y-y0).^2);   % from x0,y0 to points on the curve
cvx = convhull(xn,yn);                    % convex hull of unit vectors  

[~,i] = max(diff(xn(cvx)).^2+diff(yn(cvx)).^2);    % largest gap in the hull
x1 = xn(cvx(i)); y1=yn(cvx(i));            % vectors on both sides
x2 = xn(cvx(i+1)); y2=yn(cvx(i+1));        % of the gap     

plot(x,y)
hold on
s = linspace(0,10);
plot(x0+s*x1, y0+s*y1, 'r')                % output
plot(x0+s*x2, y0+s*y2, 'r') 
hold off
```

---

**Another approach**, which works fine if (x0,y0) is not within the convex hull of the curve.

Use `convhull` to find the convex hull of the union of the curve and of the given points `(x0,y0)`. The two edges of the convex hull that are incident to `(x0,y0)` are tangent to the curve:

[image: convex hull]

The code that produced the above picture:

```
t = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
x = 10*cos(t) + sin(7*t);
y = 6*sin(t) + cos(13*t);                 % x,y  describe the curve; 

x0 = 4; y0 = 8;                           % given point 

xe = [x0, x]; ye = [y0, y];               % put all points together 
cvx = convhull(xe,ye);                    % find convex hull 

x1 = xe(cvx(2)); y1=ye(cvx(2));           % one neighbor of (x0,y0)
x2 = xe(cvx(end-1)); y2=ye(cvx(end-1));   % another neighbor

plot(x,y)
hold on
s = linspace(0,2);
plot(x0+s*(x1-x0), y0+s*(y1-y0), 'r')     % plot the lines 
plot(x0+s*(x2-x0), y0+s*(y2-y0), 'r') 
hold off
```

Comment: In your case, if the (x0, y0) = (4, 5); it won't find the tangent point, because of the angle between the tangent lines is greater than 180. Is there a way to fix it? Thanks so much.

Comment: I see; in this case (x0,y0) is within the convex hull, so it is not among the points that `convhull` picks.. I don't have much time right now, but here's a suggestion. First, identify a half-line through (x0,y0) that does not intersect the curve. This can be done by considering the polar angles from (x0,y0) to the given points on the curve. Then apply the above algorithm to the points on one side of the curve. The idea is that now (x0,y0) is among the extreme points of the convex hull, and one of the obtained tangent lines will be tangent to the original curve (the other will be the cut line).

Comment: Or, if you mean the point is completely enclosed by the curve... then you probably need another algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Do you mean "identify a half-line through x0 y0 that DOES intersect the curve", right? So basically you want to consider the curve two parts and calculate the tangent points twice with the cut line filtered?

Comment: No, I meant "does not"... my comment is for the case when the point (x0,y0) is outside of the curve yet within its convex hull. If the point is within the curve itself, then this will not work.

Comment: Yes, the case is that the point is outside the curve and within the convex hull, like (4,5). I don't fully understand your comment now, to be honest. I will try to think about this line "This can be done by considering the polar angles from (x0,y0) to the given points on the curve. Then apply the above algorithm to the points on one side of the curve. "

Comment: Tried to use a cut-line to divide the curve into two parts, and find the tangent point for each part. But sometimes, x0,y0 still lies within the convex hull of one part, so I tried the recursive function. But the choice of the cut-line is very tricky. Do you have suggestions about the choice of the cut line? Is there another way to get the two tangent points? Thanks a million.

Comment: @Shea I came up with a different approach: see the updated answer.

Comment: Can you give me some suggestions on the similar 3D tangent plane questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288326/find-tangent-planes-from-a-given-point-outside-a-3d-curve