# Find tangent planes from a given point outside a 3D curve

Tags: matlab, 3d, shadow

This question is the 3D version of the question posted below:
[Find tangent points on a curve from a user-given point outside the curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881057/find-tangent-points-on-a-curve-from-a-user-given-point-outside-the-curve)

***Imagine a point (x0, y0, z0) outside a 3D curve. The tangent planes covers the surface on the curve which can be considered as the shadowed surface from a outside point source.***

The 3D surface consists of multiple slices (contours) in the z direction. Each slice consists (x,y) points. In consistence, the 3D curve can be generated like below:

```
t = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
x1 = 10*cos(t) + sin(7*t);
y1 = 6*sin(t) + cos(13*t);        % x1,y1  describe the first contour;  
z1 = 0;

x2 = 5*cos(t) + 0.5*sin(7*t);
y2 = 3*sin(t) + 0.5*cos(13*t);      % x2,y2  describe the first contour; 
z2 = 1;

x3 = 20*cos(2*t) + 2*sin(t);
y3 = 12*sin(t) + 2*cos(13*t);     % x2,y2  describe the first contour; 
z3 = 2;
```

This can go on for different z values and x y contours. The result should be the x,y points ranges for each z value which looks like a shadow on the 3D curve. I am not sure about convexhull being useful here in the 3D case. Any suggestions? Thanks so much for your time!

**To be clear, the figure below is an example of this problem. It has 8 contours in the z direction with z1, z2, ...., z8, each of which include a set of (x,y) points (closed contours in each slice). A outside point is set and the result of the tangent planes will be a cone that covers the 3D curve. The bottom of the cone is made up of a range of (x,y) points in EACH contour.**

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what is the object to be found. A tangent plane to 3D curve, or to a surface? If it's to a surface, you need to think more carefully of how the surface is presented: a bunch of curves in planes z=0, z=1, z=2 is not a good definition of a surface (we don't know how it looks between those planes).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Please see the bold texts I added on to this question to make it clear. The object I want to find is the points range (x,y) on each contour, and the tangent planes form a cone with its bottom being what I want to find. I agree with you on the definition of a surface. But this is the input (like the figure), not a very well defined 3D surface.